# Support Vector Machines || find hyperplane and values of w & b and the alpha value

Tags: svm

here three points are given, they are the support vectors, two of them belongs to negative class an one is positive class, here we need to find the hyper plane and values of w and b and the alpha value, please help me, I don't understand this, this is a important question for my exam

[SVM Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeiVS.png)

Comment: https://shuzhanfan.github.io/2018/05/understanding-mathematics-behind-support-vector-machines/#:~:text=Let's%20first%20consider%20the%20equation,is%20closest%20to%20the%20hyperplane.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.